# CLR function to share object

Tags: c#, sqlclr, sql-function

I have a CLR function that needs to a load couple of hundred values from a table and then perform some lookups and a calc. It works fine, my question was is there anyway to avoid that initial table lookup each time the function is called? I just put the table data into a dictionary object and I was wondering if there was a way to have multiple calls to the function to use the same object and avoid a sql call each time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you not create a model object that stores the collection? Then if the object is null, lookup, otherwise use it.